# Initiating GUI as thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread

I have a GUI class that works fine, however I have a button in that GUI class that is the supposed to open a new GUI from another class..

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

     GUI2 newGui = new GUI2();
     newGui.setVisible(true);
}
```

However, when the new GUI class (newGui) is called, it just appears as a see-through window. Is this becuase both GUI's can't run at the same time?

I'm now trying to open the new GUI as a thread, but I don't know how to do this!

```
 Thread thread = new Thread();
 thread.sleep(5000);
 thread.newGui.setVisible();
```

public void run();

This was my attempt, but unsurprisingly this didn't work.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            GUI2 newGui = new GUI2();
            newGui.setVisible(true);
        }
    };  
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Swing GUI must be created in [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), otherwise caused OPs ....

Comment: no, it can be created in the secondary / worker  threads too, if is not recommended, that is other thing, but he that wants: "I'm now trying to open the new GUI as a thread, but I don't know how to do this!"

Comment: doesn't matter Swing GUi must be created as you can to see in another answer, wrong answer, sooo crazy thats accepted, out of this thread

Comment: [it can be created in the secondary / worker threads too](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html), huuuh, sure is possible in Java7, but I miss there required EDT stuff

Answer (score 3):

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
               GUI2 newGui = new GUI2();
               newGui.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```